# how to add input to a variable?

Tags: php, forms, variables

I have this form

```
<form action="process.php" method="post"> 
Team Name: <input type="text" name="teamname" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and this is my php code

```
$teamname = $_POST['teamname'];

$namelist = "Lakers";
```

so let's say two people have submitted their team names as Spurs and Rangers

so how do I make the namelist like this and grow as more people submit their team names..

```
$namelist = "Lakers, Spurs, Rangers";
```

I have done it in array_push with arrays, but technically i can't call them.

Comment: you have to use any  stores like(database,file,etc) or you can use server cache...otherwise  you don't hold the data

Comment: how do I save them in database?

Comment: are you using any database before?would you like to see [basic-of database](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).after that you can use databse

Comment: thanks I will have look into that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the names to file/database.
variable save in the memory of the machine and deleted after the scripts done.

```
$names = array(); // empty array

$names[] = $_POST['teamname']; // add the $_POST['teamname'] to the array

var_dump($names); // prints the names array.

// now the script done, and all the data in the variables will flush from the memory.
```

Comment: I see, but would be good to know how to save them in file/database

Comment: @Lion: Yes, and it would also be good if you did your own research on that first.

Comment: @CBroe and how about to not bother commenting since I didn't asked you? if you don't have anything useful to say then don't comment

Comment: @Lion: By asking here, you are asking everyone. And SO is not a site to replace going through tutorials and documentation on your own _before_ asking about a topic.

Comment: @CBroe if the main question was about that.. then you can say it, but since im  asking "nonane" about it then you shouldn't bother to comment if it isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array to solve this issue

```
<?php
$teamname = $_POST['teamname'];
$namelist = $array("Lakers");
array_push($namelist,$teamname);
print_r($namelist);
?>
```

Comment: as you can see in my last paragraph what I said, I can't call them somehow in my code with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

using database is a simple solution.
but if you still not like to use database in this situation, you can save the variables as a session or cookie variable. it will remain after page refresh.